# NPM ERESOLVE when depending on alpha version for peer dependency

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I've been struggling in a dependency hell situation for some time.
I have two private platforms. `platform-api` depends on `platform-ui`

platform-api package.json:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@private/platform-ui": "^4"
},
```

My main Project's package.json is:

```
"dependenices": {
 "@private/platform-ui": "4.3.1-alpha.8", // version with changes
 "@private/platform-api": "2.1.29-PR-1234-SNAPSHOT", // version with changes.
}
```

Running `npm i` on My Project results in:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-project@2.0.5
npm ERR! Found: @private/platform-ui@4.3.1-alpha.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@private/platform-ui
npm ERR!   @private/platform-ui@"4.3.1-alpha.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @private/platform-ui@"^4" from @private/platform-api@2.1.29-PR-1234-SNAPSHOT
npm ERR! node_modules/@private/platform-api
npm ERR!   @private/platform-api@2.1.29-PR-1234-SNAPSHOT" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried different options for peerDependenies - `"^4.x", ">4.0-alpha".`
I want to avoid using `-force` or `-legacy-peer-deps`.

Using `node: 18.15.0` and `npm: 9.5.0` (tired also with `node: 16.16.0, npm: 8.11.0`)

Any ideas how to set the versions when working with one or both of the platforms?

Thank you!